# generate filename from username and password

Tags: android

I am developing an android app, in which I need to save the database files for each user on the server. I need to know what will be the correct way to generate the unique filenames for each user based on the login id and password to store the files on server without exposing user password, so that later it can be fetched back correctly .
As of now I am using a simple script on the server to upload the files:

```
<?php

$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

?>

Thanks.

Comment: The usernames or login id's have to be different for each user, so why not use them?

Comment: I am using email id as user id so I dont want the email ids of the users exposed if they are used as filenames.

Comment: An easy approach would be to hash the email using SHA-1 and use the hash as a filename. This will have the disadvantage of your filenames being long and looking horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use hash code of a string containing username and password. with this solution the password isn't exposed:

```
String dbFileName = (userName + password).hashCode() + ".db"; // java
$dbFileName = hash('ripemd160', $userName.$password).".db"; //php
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have two queries,1. can the hashcodes for two different username and password combination ever be same 2. will the hashcode for the same username and password always be same on all devices/android versions.

Comment: 1. The hashcode for the same username and password always will be same in any languages if algorithm be same. 2. The probability of hashcodes for two different username and password combination be same is almost near zero. If your program has many users use 64 bit hash.